# Why F# type inference doesn't work for class or interface?

Tags: f#

F# type inference works for only F# related types except for class or interface.
But I don't know why. I understand candidates will increase, but it's impossible? Are there other reasons?

Comment: Please provide an example (with code) where Type Inference does not work for class/interface.

Comment: Suppose class A has method Run, you can't write like 'fun a->a.Run()'.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply impossible to determine what the type is of an object in many circumstances. The most basic case being something like:

```
type A () = member x.bar () = ()
type B () = member x.bar () = ()

let foo x = x.bar () // Is x A or B?
```

The compiler does its best though, so if it knows what the type is at the time of usage it will happily allow you to skip the annotations:

```
type A () = member x.bar () = ()
type B () = member x.bar () = ()
let blah (x: A) = x.bar () 

let foo x =
   blah x
   x.bar () // x is known to be A thanks to above line
```

A more in depth discussion can be found in my old question here: [Why is type inference impractical for object oriented languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528534/why-is-type-inference-impractical-for-object-oriented-languages)

Comment: I understand what you say, but it's the same for record type.
If two record types have the same member, compiler select one of those.
Why it can't for classes?

Comment: The topic about subtyping in the link you told me is interesting. It may be one of the reasons.