# Scala's blend of functional with object-oriented

Tags: scala

If you were trying to explain someone how nicely Scala blends functional and object-oriented techniques, which example would you use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala versus F# question: how do they unify OO and FP paradigms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905081/scala-versus-f-question-how-do-they-unify-oo-and-fp-paradigms)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my canned [Seductions of Scala](http://polyglotprogramming.com/papers/SeductionsOfScala.pdf) talk, I end with an Actor example that uses functional-style pattern matching for determining the "kind" of message received and object-oriented-style polymorphic dispatch for one of the message "kinds" (a geometric shape to draw). It starts around slide 76.

Comment: slide 76? Your talk is too long!

Answer (score 1):

The actor API is a great example of how the strengths of both approaches are used together.  You can also look at the implementation of Map, and the way that it subclasses Function1

Answer (score 1):

Martin has pointed to `PartialFunction` as a signal example of the kind of thing that the OO/FP synthesis uniquely enables.  Specifically, you can treat it as a function and just call it, running the risk of an exception, or you can ask it first whether it's likely to throw given some argument.  The former is a natural consequence of first-class functions, and you'd expect to see it in any self-styled functional language; the latter is arguably something special.